# Why character need 1 byte and not 4?

Tags: c++

Character have an ASCII code which is a number(integer). Then why it only takes 1 byte and not 4 bytes "like an int value" to store it in the memory.

Comment: Ask yourself, how many characters are there in ASCII.  Then ask, how many bits does it take to assign a number to each of those?  How many bits is that?  Do you need 4 bytes worth of bits to represent that, or does one byte worth of bits have enough?

Comment: Perhaps an answer to the question-behind-the-question:  There are many "integer" types in C++, of varying sizes.  An integer can be 4 bytes, but it might also be 8 or 2 or 1 or some other size.

Comment: Fun fact: Some systems (Notably older Crays) did have 4 byte `char`s.  Only the minimum required size is specified by the Standard. The upper size is left unbounded.

Comment: I want a pint of ice cream (7-bits).  I have to choose between two different containers.  One is a small bowl that hold two pints (8-bits), the other is a large dairy tanker that holds 33,554,432 pints (32-bits).  Both the bowl and the tanker have more capacity than needed for the one pint of ice cream.  However, the bowl fits conveniently in my lap, whereas the tanker is significantly larger than than necessary and somewhat inconvenient to hold on my lap while watching television.

Comment: @user4581301 Is that possible? The standard requires that `sizeof(char)` is 1. A `char` must always be 1 byte. What it doesn't say is how many bits a byte has to be. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: @Kevin • the Cray byte is 32-bits.

Comment: @Eljay Ok, so it isn't that a char is 4 bytes on that system, it's that a byte is 32 bits.

Comment: Kevin's got me. I used bad terminology.

Comment: Just to make it more fun, some platforms, no longer in common use, were bit-addressable.  So a "byte" (minimum addressable unit) was 1-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASCII is a 7 bit encoding. Most modern CPU have an 8 bit byte. On a system with 8 bit byte, a single byte is sufficient to represent a character of a 7 bit encoding. There is no need to use more bytes than one.

Answer (score 0):

As the modern computer have 8 bits and a character is 7 bits it is enough to encode a integer into 1 byte rather like 4 bytes incase of integers